# Scheduled Task reminder power automate

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to build a power automate solution to overcome one of the problem in my project.

I need a flow which sends email to list users who haven't finished the task with an option to ask if they have completed the task or not. If user says yes then it should record the response with a proof of the task completion (screenshot of the task).

If user says no, then Friday it should send 2 reminder emails and on Monday it should send email every 2 hr until they complete the task, meaning they should select Yes with screenshot as attachment.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide more information. 

Where are your tasks and users stored? Sharepoint? Excel files? Database? 

How do you know if the tasks are still open? 

How do you want to ask for the screenshot? Via email? Teams? 

Why do you need notifications in that way?

Comment: It is a reminder to enter timesheet. Users stored in SharePoint. We don't have a way to know whether task is open or not, that is why sending this reminder.  Notification through emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve it as below

1. Create SharePoint list of all users
2. Create a Microsoft form with questions about whether they completed task and screenshot of same
3. Create Automated Flow to send reminder email at scheduled time with the link to form
4. Once user clicks the link in the email it will redirect the form.
5. After user submits the form it updates the SharePoint List that user has completed the task.
6. Recurring reminder to whom have not completed by reading SharePoint list